# Infinite interprocess communication between java program and a python script

Tags: java, python

I want to achieve interprocess communication between my java app and the python script that it calls through its code.
The idea is that the python script runs in an infinite while loop, accepts input, processes the input and prints the result in the console.
Meanwhile, the java app sends the input, waits for the python script to process it, and reads it from the console (using `InputStream` from the python process, omitted for brevity) when the python script is done processing. How would one go about achieving this type of communication?

**Java program**

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python pythonScript.py");

    OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
    os.write("Hello".getBytes());
    os.close();

    os = p.getOutputStream();
    os.write("World".getBytes());
    os.close();

    os = p.getOutputStream();
    os.write("quit".getBytes());
    os.close();

    }
}
```

**Python script**

```
def transformString(string):
    return "Java said: " + string

file = open("writingFile.txt", "w+")

while True:
    user_input = input('\n> ')
    message = transformString(user_input)

    if message == "quit":
        break

    file.write(message + "\n")
    print(message + "\n")

file.write("closing file...\n")
file.close()
```

The problem with the above code is that the java app can only send the input once (only "Hello" is sent) and then closes the output stream (tried without closing it). I know this because the python script never finished.
Here is the contents of the file `writingFile.txt`:

```
Java said: Hello
```

*Note: It's really important that the python script is started once, because the original script's init methods are time-consuming.
*Second note: The python's processing method also takes a bit of time, so how I don't know how to tell the java program when it's should start reading the output.

Comment: You have to flush the output stream. Yes, closing will do that too, but you don't want to close the output stream.

Comment: Maybe you also have to send a newline to python.

Comment: @Kuhn, yes I will take that note thank you. I also tried adding a new line, but same results...